# GNU C compiler sabotages undefined behaviour

Tags: c, gcc, undefined-behavior

I have an embedded project that requires at some point that I write to address 0. So naturally I try:

```
*(int*)0 = 0 ;
```

But at optimisation level 2 or higher, the gcc compiler rubs its hands and says, in effect, "That is undefined behaviour! I can do what I like! Bwahaha!" and emits an invalid instruction to the code stream!

Here is my source file:

```
void f (void)
  {
  *(int*)0 = 0 ;
  }
```

and here is the output listing:

```
    .file   "bug.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  _f
    .def    _f; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_f:
LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    $0, 0
    ud2                <-- Invalid instruction!
    .cfi_endproc
LFE0:
    .ident  "GCC: (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.3.0"
```

My question is: Why would anybody do this? What possible benefit could accrue from sabotaging code like this? Surely the obvious course of action is to issue a warning and carry on compiling?

I know the compiler is *allowed* to do this, I just wonder about the motivation of the compiler writer. It cost me two days and four engineering samples to track this down, so I'm a little peeved.

**Edited to add:** I have worked around this by using assembly language. So I'm not looking for solutions. I'm just curious why anybody would think this compiler behaviour was a good idea.

Comment: File a bug report.  It's obviously not UB on your platform.

Comment: Have you tried using a (`volatile`) variable for the pointer? As in `volatile int *null_pointer = (int *) 0;`, and then use that variable when needed?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The representation of the null pointer on my system is 0. So I am writing through the null pointer, which is UB.

Comment: @TonyK  No, you are writing through a value that happens to be a null pointer constant.  The mistaken belief that the value zero is actually `NULL` is what caused the C standards committee to have to define zero as a "null pointer constant" as a sop to all those developers who failed to understand that no, `0` is **NOT** "the `NULL` pointer".  "The null pointer" is `NULL` and nothing else.

Comment: It is a convenience.  `ud2` is the code generated by `__builtin_trap()`

Comment: First, it is not clear the compiler writers decided that this particular undefined behavior should be replaced with a `ud2` instruction. In general, code may have sequences such as `if (A) B; else C; if (d) E; else F;` in which it is possible that B and E are executed or B and F or C and E but never C and F. Further, depending on the specific code, the compiler might not be able to deduce this fact, even if the author had a formal proof of it. Further down, there might be code that has undefined behavior in certain cases, and the compiler replaces that undefined behavior with a placeholder…

Comment: … Later, during optimization, cases such as that are often eliminated during optimization, so no `ud2` is actually generated. However, that case might be one that occurs only if C and F are both executed, and the compiler is unable to prove it can be eliminated. Then the final code ends up with a `ud2` in it. Yet the actual program may be a completely working, strictly conforming C program that never executes `ud2`…

Comment: @Eric, you are over-thinking this. That is the whole of the source file that you see up there. Calling `f` will inexorably cause the `ud2` to be executed (assuming the `movl` executes, which it does on my platform).

Comment: … Also consider what happens if the compiler compilers this code simplistically, generating a store to address zero. In a system in which address zero is accessible (but should not be written by a correct program, possibly excepting the kernel and/or special circumstances), this store would execute silently, not performing the intended task and possibly corrupting necessary data. On the other hand, if the compiler generates `ud2`, and the program executes this code path, then the bug will be obvious and will likely be found during testing.

Comment: @TonyK: Compilers are not written just for the one sequence of code you show. They are written for every possible sequence of code, so I am explaining how designing for that requirement can result in the compiler’s behavior for this code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes, that is why I suggested that the compiler issue a warning.

Comment: On the other hand, Clang does warn: “indirection of non-volatile null pointer will be deleted, not trap [-Werror,-Wnull-dereference]”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I wish my compiler had said that :-)

Comment: I think perhaps what you want is `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks`.  Conversely, if you omit this option but use `-Wnull-dereference`, you do get a warning.

Comment: Counterpoint: "Why does the compiler bloat my executable by compiling 5000 lines of code when it's obviously unreachable because of the null pointer dereference before it?"

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thank you for that information! I have added `-Wnull-dereference` to my makefile to avoid such problems in the future.

Comment: But again, if you actually want the compiler to write to address 0 and then continue compiling the code as written, `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` is what you want instead.  I would guess you're using a compiler that is targeted for a real OS, e.g. Linux, on which a program in fact cannot continue executing after a null pointer dereference because page 0 is not mapped, and so it's not unreasonable for `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks` to be the default. [...]

Comment: In principle if you are compiling for an embedded system you ought to be using a gcc specifically  configured to target that system, and in setting up that configuration, you were supposed to have noticed that `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks` was more appropriate and made it the default.  I think that's what the gcc developers would say, anyway.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: But then again, `clang` does actually delete the dereference.  `gcc` leaves it in, perhaps under the assumption that you are trying to transfer control to your SIGSEGV handler or the like, but then just doesn't bother to generate any of the "unreachable" code that follows.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I am actually using the GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain compiler `arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe`. So it should be more tolerant, I would have thought.

Comment: But the code you posted is x86?

Comment: @NateEldredge: That was just to show people what the compiler does, without complicating the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on GCC internals, and this is more of a "post hoc" attempt to explain its behavior.  But maybe it will be helpful.)

> the gcc compiler rubs its hands and says, in effect, "That is undefined behaviour! I can do what I like! Bwahaha!" and emits an invalid instruction to the code stream!

I won't deny that there are cases where GCC does more or less that, but here there's a little more going on, and there is some method to its madness.

As I understand it, GCC isn't treating the null dereference as totally undefined here; it is making some assumptions about what it does.  Its handling of null dereferences is controlled by a flag called `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks`, which is probably enabled by default when you turn on optimizations.  From the [manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options):

> `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks`
>
> Assume that programs cannot safely dereference null pointers, and that no code or data element resides at address zero. This option
> enables simple constant folding optimizations at all optimization
> levels. In addition, other optimization passes in GCC use this flag to
> control global dataflow analyses that eliminate useless checks for
> null pointers; **these assume that a memory access to address zero
> always results in a trap**, so that if a pointer is checked after it has
> already been dereferenced, it cannot be null.
>
> Note however that in some environments this assumption is not true. Use -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks to disable this optimization
> for programs that depend on that behavior.
>
> This option is enabled by default on most targets. On Nios II ELF, it defaults to off. On AVR, CR16, and MSP430, this option is
> completely disabled.
>
> Passes that use the dataflow information are enabled independently at different optimization levels.

So, if you are intending to actually access address 0, or if for some other reason your code will go on executing after the dereference, then you want to disable this with `-fno-delete-null-pointer-checks`.  That will achieve the "carry on compiling" part of what you want.  It will not give you warnings, however, presumably under the assumption that such dereferences are intentional.

---

But under default options, why are you seeing the generated code that you do, with the undefined instruction, and why isn't there a warning?  I would guess that GCC's logic is running as follows:

- Because `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks` is in effect, the compiler assumes that execution will not continue past the null dereference, but instead will trap.  How the trap will be handled, it doesn't know: maybe program termination, maybe a signal or exception handler, maybe a `longjmp` up the stack.  The null dereference itself is emitted as requested, perhaps under the assumption that you are intentionally exercising your trap handler.  But either way, whatever code comes after the null dereference is now unreachable.
- So now it does what any reasonable optimizing compiler does with unreachable code: it doesn't emit it.  In your case, that's nothing but a `ret`, but whatever it is, as far as GCC is concerned it would just be wasted bytes of memory, and should be omitted.

  You might think you should get a warning here, but GCC has a longstanding design decision not to warn about unreachable code, on the grounds that such warnings tended to be inconsistent and the false positives would do more harm than good.  See for instance https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-help/2011-05/msg00360.html.
- However, as a safety feature, GCC emits an undefined instruction (`ud2` on x86) in place of the omitted unreachable code.  The idea, I believe, is that just in case execution somehow does continue past the null dereference, it is better for the program to die, than to go off into the weeds and try to execute whatever memory contents happen to come next.  (And indeed this can happen even on systems that do unmap the zero page; for instance, if you do `struct huge *p = NULL; p->x = 0;`, GCC understands this as a null dereference, even though `p->x` may not be on the zero page at all, and could conceivably be located at an accessible address.)

There is a warning flag, `-Wnull-dereference`, that will trigger a warning on your blatant null dereference.  However, it only works if `-fdelete-null-pointer-checks` is enabled.

---

When would GCC's behavior be useful?  Here's an example, maybe contrived, but it might get the idea across.  Imagine your program has some allocation function that might fail:

```
struct foo *p = get_foo();
// do other stuff for a while
if (!p) {
    // 5000 lines of elaborate backup plan in case we can't get a foo
}
frob(p->bar);
```

Now imagine that you redesign `get_foo()` so that it can't fail.  You forget to take out your "backup plan" code, but you go ahead and use the returned object right away:

```
struct foo *p = get_foo();
frob(p->bar);
// do other stuff for a while
if (!p) {
    // 5000 lines of elaborate backup plan in case we can't get a foo
}
```

The compiler doesn't know, *a priori*, that `get_foo()` will always return a valid pointer.  But it can see that you've dereferenced it, and thus can assume that execution will only continue past that point if the pointer was not null.  Therefore, it can tell that the elaborate backup plan is unreachable and should be omitted, which will save you a lot of bloat in your binary.

---

Incidentally, the situation with clang. Although as Eric Postpischil points out you do get a warning, what you don't get is an actual load from address 0: clang omits it and just emits `ud2`.   This is what "doing whatever it likes" would really look like, and if you were hoping to exercise your page zero  trap handler, you are out of luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, clang and gcc have no option to register-allocate automatic variables whose address isn't taken, or consolidate loads and stores that don't aren't separated by pointer conversions, address-of-union-member operations, or volatile-qualified accesses, etc. but generally process most actions the Standard characterizes as UB, save for those that would disrupt storage owned by the implementation, "in a documented fashion characteristic of the environment" as would befit an implementation designed to be suitable for low-level programming.

Answer (score 0):

In describing Undefined Behavior, the Standard refers to it as resulting "upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data,", and the authors of the Standard clarify their intentions more clearly in the published Rationale: "Undefined behavior gives the implementor license not to catch certain program errors that are difficult to diagnose. It also identifies areas of possible conforming language extension: the implementor may augment the language by providing a definition of the officially undefined behavior."  The question of when to extend the language in such fashion--treating various forms of UB as non-portable but *correct*, was left as a Quality of Implementation issue outside the Standard's jurisdiction.

The maintainers of clang and gcc take the view that the phrase "non-portable or erroneous" should be interpreted as synonymous with "erroneous", since the Standard would not forbid such an interpretation.  If a compiler will never be used to process non-portable programs that will never be fed erroneous data, such an interpretation will sometimes allow them to process some strictly conforming programs which are fed exclusively valid data more quickly than would otherwise be possible, at the expense of making them less suitable for other purposes.  I personally would view the range of programs that a compiler can usefully process reasonably efficiently as a much better metric of quality than the efficiency with which a compiler can process strictly-conforming programs, but people who are using compilers for different purposes may have different views about what would make a compiler more or less useful for those purposes.